# Jacoco nodeps: ClassNotFound com.vladium.emma.rt.RT

Tags: gradle, jacoco-plugin

### Description

Gradle 5.6.4

Android Studio 3.6.3

#### Problem

In a file under the `androidTest` directory, I had such a line of code and got `ClassNotFoundException`.

```sh
Class<?> emmaRTClass = Class.forName("com.vladium.emma.rt.RT");
```

#### Project Structure

```sh
.
├── build.gradle
├── subproject.main (app)
       ├── src
       ├── ...
       └── build.gradle
├── subproject1
├── subproject2
 ...
```

#### build.gradle

`./build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.jacocoVersion="0.8.2"
    ...
    dependencies {
         ...
         classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:$jacocoVersion"
    }
}
```

`subproject.main/build.gradle`

```
...
dependencies {
     ...
     jacocoAnt 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.8.1:nodeps'
}

apply plugin: 'jacoco'
...
```

According to [this](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/repo.html),

> | org.jacoco | org.jacoco.ant | nodeps | Ant Tasks (all dependencies included) |

#### gradle dependencies:

To see the dependencies for `subproject.main`

```sh
 $ ./gradlew app:dependencies | grep jacoco
```

The output is

```
jacocoTestReport_test
jacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.2
jacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.8.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.8.1
     |    \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.1 (*)
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.1
jacocoRuntime
```

`ls ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`

```
 org.jacoco
 ├── org.jacoco.core
 └── org.jacoco.report
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it! It is because the default value of `testCoverageEnabled` is `false` as shown in the following configuration. **Just set `testCoverageEnabled true` unconditionally.**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
       ...
       if (isFromServer()) {
           testCoverageEnabled true
       }
    }
}
```